# Disallow access to twitter accounts automatically [iOS, Fabric]

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, twitter-fabric

I need my iOS to logout of twitter and the only way to make this work is to disallow access to twitter accounts on the device. Of course I do not want my app users to have to select something in order for it to work. Is there a way to remove that alert view and always deny the apps access to twitter accounts automatically?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: Want the answer too...